# How to receive email from system, using Intent Filter?

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I searched for the query online and figured the `intent-filter` in the AndroidManifest.xml file. However, I am still unable to find how to receive the clicked email id in my application.

My problem

- Suppose I receive a message on my WhatsApp chat box containing an email id (xyz@test.com).
- On clicking the email id (xyz@test.com), I want my app to open. (Figured, using Intent-filter)
- Upon opening my application, I want the email id (xyz@test.com) to be automatically copied into the EditText on my activity.

I have tried with the following function:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String x = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

*Toast is for checking whether string is being received or no.

However, the toast appears empty,showing that the string is not getting received.

Comment: "I have tried with the following function" -- what makes you think that there will be an `EXTRA_EMAIL` value? What is the `<intent-filter>` that you are responding to?

Comment: I was using EXTRA_EMAIL because I couldn't find any other email key value in intents. I responding to Android System clicks on Email addresses throughout the system.

Comment: "I responding to Android System clicks on Email addresses throughout the system" -- that is not possible. What is the **specific** `<intent-filter>` (or filters) that you are responding to? Then, and only then, can we advise you as to how to get an email address from the corresponding `Intent`, or whether that particular `Intent` does not have to do with email addresses.

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
                <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>

I am using these intent-filters. Hope this may help. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an app invokes your activity via an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, there is no documented means for that app to give you an email address.

If an app invokes your activity via an `ACTION_SENDTO` `Intent`, the email address will be in the `Uri`. That `Uri` scheme should be `mailto:` (as that what your filter is restricting it to). I *think* you get the address via `getSchemeSpecificPart()` on the `Uri`, though I have not tried this.

Note that there is no requirement for an app to launch any third-party activity when the user clicks an email address, let alone one of the two that you that you have set up via the `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: Thank you  so much for this. However, could you please help me a little with code for the same (uri) or give me a link to any reference/example for the same?

Comment: @TanishqSharma: Um, you call `getIntent()` on the `Activity` to get the `Intent`. You call `getData()` on the `Intent` to get the `Uri`. You call `getSchemeSpecificPart()` on the `Uri` to get the email address, I think.

Comment: Tried, unfortunate. _java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getSchemeSpecificPart()' on a null object reference_

@CommonWare

Comment: @TanishqSharma: Then your activity is being started without a `Uri`. That does not make much sense given your stated `<intent-filter>`, as both `ACTION_VIEW` and `ACTION_SENDTO` need a `Uri` to be useful.

Comment: @CommonWare - Got it! Its resolved :) The error was because I had to put the extracting function of string in a condition before checking the null. However when I use it by clicking on WhatsApp message containing email, it works perfect :D How do I upvote this? Love your help for this. :)

Comment: @TanishqSharma: I am glad that it is now working for you. To cast votes, click the up or down arrows above the large number to the side of the answer. To accept answers, click the outline of the checkmark below the arrows and number.

Comment: @CommonWare Thankyou. Accepted the answer, but cannot up-vote due to less reputation. Thankyou, anyways. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the email intent is really designed for sending/composing an email, not for copying data from the email into your application.  See here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email

If you wanted to get an email address for someone, you may want to try the contacts intent instead:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Contacts

Comment: Thank you for reply. My problem is bit different from here. I just want to display the email clicked any where in the android, in my application.

For example, if someone clicks the email from message, whatsapp or any where else, I want my app to open and receive that email address.